# PHP Version which includes Timezone Asia/Beijing?

Tags: php, timezone

I'm developing a scheduling app for broadcasting people involved in the olympic wintergames in China.

They are supposed to be able to choose different timezones as a ruler for their schedule displays. As the Olympic games take place in Beijing, they chose "(+08:00) Beijing" from my php generated list based on the php functions.

The frontend app crashed somehow (moment timezone library doesn't know it).

The problem is: *There isn't supposed to be a Beijing timezone!* On different servers, including my development environment, the option is simply not there and the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/de/timezones.asia.php) also tells us, that there is no "Beijing" timezone.

So, how come the option is shown? Are there special php versions? What can I tell the admins?

I use the `timezone_identifiers_list` php function.

Comment: This isn't really so much dependent on the PHP version, but on what timezone database it uses. As https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php says, _"Note: This list is based upon the timezone database version 2021.5."_, and _"Note: The latest version of the timezone database can be installed via PECL's » timezonedb."_

Comment: (Btw., are you talking about the Paralympics? Because the actual Beijing Winter Games are over by now ...)

Comment: Can you not pick a zone that does exist and has the same offset from Zulu like `Asia/Hong_Kong`

Comment: Just use [CST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cst-china), but do no confuse it with [CST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cst)

Comment: @CBroe that pretty much looks like the answer I expected. So go ahead with an official answer and I'll accept it :)  And about Olympics vs Paralympics: Actually it's both, the problem appeared some time ago, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really so much dependent on the PHP version, but on what timezone database it uses.

As https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php states,

> Note: This list is based upon the timezone database version 2021.5.

and

> Note: The latest version of the timezone database can be installed via PECL's » timezonedb."